# Java Hibernate tag substitution not working for a large field in an Oracle database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

In a simple select SQL, for a `VARCHAR2(50)` field, the tag substitution works fine:

```
ERRORMSG LIKE (:errorMsg)||'%'
```

However, for another field defined as `VARCHAR2(4000)`, it only seems to be working for the first character (or the first couple of characters if they are numeric):

```
VARDATA LIKE (:varData)||'%'
```

For example: if `errorMsg = "my test string"` in the code, the query works just fine. However, if `varData = "my test string"` the query returns no records (even though it should). However, if I use `varData = "m"`, I would get the expected result.

Other than the size of the fields in the database, I don't see any differences. I don't get why it works for `ERRORMSG` and not for `VARDATA`.

Here is what I hope is relevant from the xml configuration:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="pooledDS" jndi-name="java:jboss/myDS"/>

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
     <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
       <property name="dataSource" ref="pooledDS"/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="loadTimeWeaver" class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.jboss.JBossLoadTimeWeaver" />
   <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
     <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>
         <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
         <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
         <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>   
   </bean>
 <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="pooledDS"/>
         <!-- added provider -->
         <property name="persistenceProvider">
                <bean class="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
          </property>
          <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />
          <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
         <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
          <property name="loadTimeWeaver" ref="loadTimeWeaver"/>
          <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
                 <map>
                        <entry key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction" />
                        <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                        <entry key="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
                        <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
                 </map>
          </property>     
    </bean>
   <bean id="persistenceAnnotation" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
   </bean>
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManagerBean"/>
    <bean id="txManagerBean" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="pooledDS"/>
    </bean>
```

Spring version is 3.2.5. Hibernate 3. Running on JBoss EAP 6.1.1. Oracle 11g.

Any ideas?

In case it helps...I did try going around Hibernate and got the same result, which leads me to believe that it might be something in how JBoss is configured to talk to Oracle.  Here is my database connection:

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/myDS" pool-name="My Connection Pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@<url>:1521:<id></connection-url>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <new-connection-sql>select sysdate from dual</new-connection-sql>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                    <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>MY_APP</user-name>
                    <password>${VAULT::myDB::MyOracle::1}</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
                <timeout>
                    <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                </timeout>
     </datasource>
     <drivers>
                <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
                  <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

Hopefully someone sees something I've missed....

Comment: Added datasource information to the question...seems like the issue might be how JBoss and Oracle are working together here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No issues with any specific component. Hibernate, Oracle drivers, JBoss, et. al. are fine.

The root cause of the issue was that someone modified the code that builds the values to go into the query so that it change the case all all input fields to upper case. Hence the query wouldn't get back any results (unless you were lucky and the first character was also upper case).

Removing that extra bit of code cleared up the issue.

So the caveat for everyone who runs into something similar is to make certain what happens with the SQL before it is actually processed by Hibernate (or some other JPA provider).